# Outlook 2007 always asks for a network password on Windows 7 Professional

Tags: windows-7, password, outlook-2007

Outlook 2007 always asks for a network password on Windows 7 Professional.
Although, I have setup the network password cache in my user account!

Any help??

Comment: More info needed. Are you connecting to Exchange? Are you part of a domain?

Answer (score 1):

Strangely solved after a complete re-installation from scratch of Windows 7 and now using Outlook 2010

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently on WindowsXP so I cannot give 100% accurate guidelines, but I'll do my best.

We are experiencing the same problem. One of the things that seem to help, is going into Control Panel and open up Credential Manager. There are a couple categories in there, one of them is something with "generic" in it. Under that, you should find your Outlook/Exchange credentials. Open that up, insert the password again and you should be set.

It's probably best to do this while Outlook is not started.

This solution hasn't been properly tested yet, but if it helps please let me know, it might help for our users as well.